# Copy an array of sheets and renumber them

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I want to add an extra week through a macro. My Workbook, contains all workhours for my colleagues for several projects from monday to sunday and a summary for that week. I would like to add an extra week with the same references to that summary. So I set up an Array.

Everytime I want to run this macro I would like te copy the array to the back and add an extra number for the new week (renumber / renaming the sheets), so I got week 1, week 2, week 3 with the right days (monday (week) 1, monday (week) 2, monday (week) 3 and so on).

This is already what i got:

```
Sub Macro1()

With Sheets(Array("Week 1", "Monday 1", "Tuesday 1", "Wednesday 1", "Thursday 1", _
    "Friday 1", "Saturday 1", "Sunday 1"))

Sheets(Array(""Week 1", "Monday 1", "Tuesday 1", "Wednesday 1", "Thursday 1", _
    "Friday 1", "Saturday 1", "Sunday 1")).Copy After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count)

End With
```

When i runn this macro i got this:

picture of `macro1()`

[image]

I would like that sheet "monday 1 (2)" is automaticly renumberd to: "monday 2" and so on for the whole week.

And when i add an another week it adds sheet: Week 3, Monday 3 .. Sunday 3

Comment: Not sure if I understand right. You want to add a new sheet for every week? Or a new sheet for every week an dayweek?

Comment: Do you mean to make copies of the existing sheets but rename that as latest week e.g. Week2 and have these at the front of the workbook?

Comment: You could have an inputbox to prompt for the week number to update to , then have code to copy the array of sheets which are -1 from this testing with Right$(Worksheet.Name,1)......, then rename those as +1 so you have a copied set of sheets with the new numbering at the front.

Comment: Hi, I would like to have a full new week, so the array sheets:  (summary) week 1 + monday 1 ... sunday 1 is coppied and renumberd for a new week. so i got monday 2 and so on. next time i runn that macro, i want week 3 to be added.    ---> there within (i will need to code that later on) the available budget for that new week minus the previous weeks.

Comment: @QHarr  updated my question [link]https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qh5E1.jpg

Answer (score 0):

This is without any real error handling. I have used `currWeek` in a loop for demonstration purposes. You could set its value outside of a loop and simply have it be the latest week. You could also prompt user to input this value via an `inputbox`.  `Sub remove()` is just to get rid of added sheet during testing.
This gives you the general structure.

If you had a sheet called `"Main"`, and in Cell `B2` put the number of weeks you wanted to add, the following code checks what the current maximum week is (based on the last current worksheet name) and then loops from this adding weeks.

```
Sub AddWeeks2()

Dim startWksheetCount As Long
Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Dim currWeek As Long

Dim startWeek As Long
Dim endWeek As Long

Dim tempStr As String
tempStr = wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count).Name

startWeek = CInt(Right$(tempStr, Len(tempStr) - InStr(1, tempStr, " ")))
endWeek = startWeek + wb.Sheets("Main").Range("B2") - 1

If Not IsNumeric(startWeek) Or Not IsNumeric(endWeek) Then

    MsgBox "Please ensure start week and end week are numbers"
    Exit Sub

Else

    For currWeek = startWeek To endWeek

        startWksheetCount = wb.Sheets.Count

        wb.Sheets(Array("Week " & currWeek, "Monday " & currWeek, "Tuesday " & currWeek, "Wednesday " & currWeek, "Thursday " & currWeek, _
            "Friday " & currWeek, "Saturday " & currWeek, "Sunday " & currWeek)).Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)

        Dim currSheet As Long
        Dim sheetName As String
        Dim cutOff As Long

        For currSheet = startWksheetCount + 1 To wb.Sheets.Count

            sheetName = wb.Sheets(currSheet).Name

            If Not Left(sheetName, 4) = "Week" Then

                cutOff = InStr(1, sheetName, "y")
                wb.Sheets(currSheet).Name = Left$(sheetName, cutOff) & " " & CStr(currWeek + 1)

            Else

                wb.Sheets(currSheet).Name = "Week " & CStr(currWeek + 1)

            End If

        Next currSheet

    Next currWeek

End If

End Sub






Private Sub remove()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wsName As String

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    wsName = ws.Name

    If Not wsName = "Main" Then

        If Right$(wsName, 1) <> CStr(1) Or _
           Len(Right$(wsName, Len(wsName) - InStr(1, wsName, " "))) > 1 Then

           ws.Delete

        End If

    End If


Next ws

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```